# proving continuity of decreasing measurable sets, without using same results for increasing measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

There is a well known result in measure theory that says that:

Suppose that $(\Omega,A, \mu)$ is a measure space.

> If $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq A$, with $E_1 \supset E_2...$, and
>   $\mu(E_1) < \infty$, then
>
> $\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(E_n)$.

I am wondering if it is possible to prove this directly, without using the corresponding property for increasing sequences, and using that $E_1$\ $E_{n}$ is increasing and that $\cup(E_1$\ $E_n)=E_1$\ $\cap(E_n) $. This is the only proof for this I have seen, where they use the other property, could you prove it directly instead?

Answer (score -1):

Verify that the assumptions imply

$$
\chi_{E_n} \to \chi_{\bigcap_m E_m},
$$

with pointwise convergence, where $\chi_E$ denotes the indicator function of the set $E$.

Then use the dominated convergence theorem (with dominating function $\chi_{E_1}$) to conclude that

$$
\mu(E_n) =\int \chi_{E_n} d\mu \to \int \chi_{\bigcap_m E_m} d\mu = \mu(\bigcap_m E_m). 
$$